# WLAN USB works with TKIP but not AES?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Alright, so I have a Realtek RTL8188cu Wireless Lan 802.11n USB2.0 network adapter, and my router is a Model:SMCD3GNV with it's mode set to 802.11 b/g/n, and it's security type is WPAWPA2-PSK (TKIP/AES)

My adapter's settings are as follows: Bandwith: 20_40MHz, network type: infrastructure, wifi Config: wifi (out of Wifi/Preformance), Wireless Mode: IEEE 802.11b/g/n

My provider is Comcast, and finally my question is why can't I connect to my router while in AES encryption mode? (Works perfectly fine in TKIP, but I think that makes it use G instead of N, and I'm trying to make my speeds faster (Can't even load a 3:00 YT video without buffering) and my ping skyrockets from 70 to 3000 when I load a video/download something)

Note: as the tag says, I'm on Windows 7 (x64)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realize is that TKIP means that you are not really one WPA2. Instead, you are shifted back to WEP with a few modification (for more technical gory details, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol)).

It could be that your router, or NIC (or both) do not support WPA2.

If that is the case, then there is nothing that you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I fixed it. This post helped me out. It says that unless I have a dual banded router the router is only going to go the speed of the sloest device on it (Which was my Cell Phone :\ ).

Link to post (Not sure if this site has anything bad on it, so use at own risk) http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showpost.php?s=06eff7922f28defb2aeba65b108c4d0c&p=7014588&postcount=2